# Rails 4: alternative for ActiveRecord 'all' as it is now deprecated

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

Is `find_each` an acceptable replacement for the ActiveRecord function `all` in version 4.0.0 of ActiveRecord?

For example, previously I had:

```
all_users = User.all
```

which produces a warning stating something along the lines of ActiveRelation:all is deprecated.

As a replacement I came up with:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  all_users += user
end
```

Is this acceptable, or should I be doing it another way?

I understand the reason behind using `find_each` is because of 'batching' which will allow the query to stop running if there is a very large dataset. Let's assume for this case that the dataset is small.

**EDIT**

It seems the deprecation error only comes up when you use conditons, eg:

```
User.all(:conditions => ["name like ?", "%bob%"])
```

produces:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to
>   eager-load a rel ation, you can call #load (e.g.
>   `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want  to get an array of
>   records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.wher
>   e(published: true).to_a`). (called from irb_binding at (irb):8)

The correct replacement for the above appears to be:

```
User.where("name like ?", "%bob%")
```

Comment: I don't think the question linked is quite the same as this as they are only wanting 5 records with an order by. Also when searching for `ActiveRecord all deprecation` that article didn't come up, is it because of the title? Hallucynogenyc's answer didn't work when I tried it in irb. EG: Using `User` or `User.to_a` seems to be invalid.

Comment: No worries, FYI - it's not rails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Model.all` isn't deprecated in Rails 4, but it has changed. Instead of returning an array of all of the records, it returns an ActiveRecord Relation which is significantly faster.

`Model.all` is designed to deprecate `Model.scoped` which previously lazy loaded the records. `Model.all` can now be used for easier chaining of methods instead of `scoped`.

You can read all about it here in this [article](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013).

Comment: Isn't `.all` deprecated though?

Comment: Yeah, the new syntax (I guess) is `Model.scoped` to make it easier to chain.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd use `Model.scoped` instead of `Model.all`? Is it better than using `Model.find_each` and why?

Comment: So using `find_each` will iterate over every record. `scoped` will just lazy load the records, which is way faster. With a small data set it's not a huge deal, but for scalability you would want to use `scoped` over `find each` in a block.

Comment: Thanks. So to get all records you just type `Model.scoped` ?

Comment: Yeah. `Model.scoped` will grab all of the records.

Comment: Thanks Colton. Perhaps adjust your answer and i'll try this tonight, and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I had it completely backwards. I'm not sure why you would be getting a deprecation warning on `#all`, because that is the method replacing `#scoped`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39791/discussion-between-rots-and-colton-fent)